# Treat WHERE IN parameters as AND and not OR

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I have this table structure/data :

[image]

I want to select the `row_id`(s) that have the combination of (97,6,2) **AND** (99,1,4) on (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) respectively.

In this example, we want to get the `row_id` 8664 as it respects this condition.

What I did is to use the `where in` statement like following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
where row_id in 
   (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
    WHERE (attribute_id, store_id,value) 
    IN ( (99,1,4),(97,6,1) ))
```

This outputs the lines that have (99,1,4) **OR** (97,6,1).

I tried this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
where row_id in 
    (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int 
    WHERE (attribute_id, store_id,value) IN (99,1,4) 
    AND (attribute_id, store_id,value) IN(97,6,1) )
```

But I have `#1241 - Operand should contain 3 column(s)`

How do I manage to select the lines that validates the two conditions together ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy.

Vectors `(99, 1, 4)` and `(97, 6, 1)` must be in parentheses: `((99, 1, 4))` and `((97, 6, 1))`.

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT row_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
WHERE row_id IN (
    SELECT row_id 
    FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
    WHERE (attribute_id, store_id, value) IN ((99, 1, 4))
          OR (attribute_id, store_id, value) IN ((97, 6, 1))
)
```

or even better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT row_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
WHERE row_id IN (
    SELECT row_id 
    FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
    WHERE (attribute_id, store_id, value) IN ((99, 1, 4), (97, 6, 1))
)
```

Comment: Of course, you are right @FabianPijcke, thank you. I corrected this.

Answer (score 1):

Write your where condition out like this

```
WHERE (attribute_id = 99 AND store_id = 1 AND value = 4)
OR (attribute_id = 99 AND store_id = 6 AND value = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT row_id FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE row_id IN 
(SELECT row_id FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
WHERE (attribute_id = 99 AND store_id = 1 AND value = 4)
OR (attribute_id = 97 AND store_id = 6 AND value = 1))
```

Comment: It's the same as WHERE IN, I like to have AND between the two conditions

Comment: the **WHERE** condition that you are trying to impose is quiet not feasible. as per your condition, a single record can have __attribute_id__ both 99 and 97 at the same time, which is illogical.